# How to access vuex store from `index.html`?

Tags: javascript, cookies, vuex, vuejs3

I've to embed some script tags to my vue web application. I am not sure where to add it, but I choose to add them in `index.html`. where `#app` div lives.

Below `index.html` I have to embed at least 3 or 4 script tags and create some cookies that change the language, set preference of user where they want to be tracked or not. And for that I need to access **vuex** store.

If I try to access a property of `store` form `index.html` like `this.$store.getters.getActiveLanguage;` I get errors.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getters' of undefined
```

Sounds like I can't access store from here. How do I solve it, can anyone help? thank you in advance

edit: full code example here in `index.html`

```
    <!-- Cookie Consent by https://www.FreePrivacyPolicy.com -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="//www.freeprivacypolicy.com/public/cookie-consent/3.1.0/cookie-consent.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    cookieconsent.run({ notice_banner_type: "interstitial", consent_type: "express", palette: "dark", language: "en" });
  });
</script>

<!-- easy -->
<!-- const language = .localSorage.getItem("language"); -->
<script type="text/plain" cookie-consent="functionality">
  document.cookie = "functionalityCookie=en";
  this.$store.getters.getActiveLanguage; 
</script>

<script type="text/plain" cookie-consent="tracking">
  document.cookie = "trackingCookie=true";
</script>

<script type="text/plain" cookie-consent="strictly-necessary">
  document.cookie = "strictlyNecessaryCookie=true";
</script>

<!-- end of easy-->

<noscript
  >Cookie Consent by <a href="https://www.FreePrivacyPolicy.com/free-cookie-consent/" rel="nofollow noopener">FreePrivacyPolicy.com</a></noscript
>
```

Comment: It's hard to say what the problem is without more example code. But `this.$store` will only work inside Vue for example inside a component. Anywhere else it will simple not work.

Comment: I just added full code, I also indicated how I want to access store, but sounds I can't access it. What other solutions do you think is best to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

In your case `this` is equal to `window`

What I would do is on `mounted` run `cookieconsent.run` where you can set the current language of the user

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  store: store,
  mounted () {
    const language = this.$store.getters.getActiveLanguage;
    cookieconsent.run({ 
      notice_banner_type: "interstitial", 
      consent_type: "express", 
      palette: "dark", 
      language: language 
    });
  }
})
```

Comment: I already mounted another vue instance in `#app`, isn't going to create problems

Comment: No that is not what I meaned, I mean that you should add it to your existing Vue insurance